# Counting Words from a String

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I'm supposed to create a method that count the number of words in the sentence that meet or exceed int minLength. For instance, if the minimum length given is 4, your program should only count words that are at least 4 letters long.

The words can will separated by one or more spaces. Non-letter characters (spaces, punctuation, digits, etc.) may be present, but they don't count towards the length of the word.

```
    public static int countWords(String original, int minLength) {
    original = original.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z\\s]", "").replaceAll("[0-9]", "");
    String[] words = original.split("\\s+");


    for(String word : words){ System.out.println(word); }

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
        if (words[i].length() >= minLength) {
            count++;
        } else if (words[i].length() < minLength || minLength == 0) {
            count = 0;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Number of words in sentence: " + count);
    return count;
}
```

Okay so I changed my code, but the counter is now off by one. Say I input the following : Spain is a beautiful country; the beache's are warm, sandy and spotlessly clean."

The output I receive is...
Spain
is
a
beautiful
country
the
beaches
are
warm
sandy
and
spotlessly
clean
Number of words in sentence: 10

The number of word is off by one, it should be 11. Looks like it's not counting the last word in the sentence. I'm not sure where the issue stems from considering I only changed the replaceAll to include an escape character.

Comment: Granted, I haven't tested the code, but it looks like an issue with your regex and how you're doing the split. I'd give it some more thought before giving up.

Comment: Replacing things with spaces doesn't really achieve your aims...

Answer (score 2):

You are getting incorrect result, because inside the else if condition, count is updated to 0.
So, As soon as a word appears with length < minLength, your counter resets.
You can remove the else if condition and that should fix your code.

Additionally, following are 2 more options to write the same code, with required comments to understand what is happening at each step.

#### Option 1:

```
private static long countWords(final String sentence, final int minLength) {
  // Validate the input sentence is not null or empty.
  if (sentence == null || sentence.isEmpty()) {
    return 0;
  }

  long count = 0;
  // split the sentence by spaces to get array of words.
  final String[] words = sentence.split(" ");
  for (final String word : words) { // for each word
    // remove unwanted characters from the word.
    final String normalizedWord = word.trim().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
    // if the length of word is greater than or equal to minLength provided, increment the counter.
    if (normalizedWord.length() >= minLength) {
      count++;
    }
  }

  return count;
}
```

#### Option 2: [Using Java 8 stream]

```
private static long countWords(final String sentence, final int minLength) {
  // Validate the input sentence is not null or empty.
  if (sentence == null || sentence.isEmpty()) {
    return 0;
  }

  return Stream.of(sentence.split(" "))
      .filter(word -> word.trim().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "").length() >= minLength)
      .count();
}
```

For input string: "Spain is a beautiful country; the beache's are warm, sandy and spotlessly clean."

```
Min Length: 3. Output: 11
Min Length: 4. Output: 8
Min Length: 5. Output: 7
```

For input string: "This would work like magic!"

```
Min Length: 4. Output: 5
Min Length: 5. Output: 2
Min Length: 6. Output: 0
```

For input string: "hello$hello"

```
Min Length: 4. Output: 1
Min Length: 5. Output: 1
Min Length: 6. Output: 1
```

Comment: Hint: I am not sure if throwing streams at a newbie (without any further explanation) is really the best idea.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.Added another solution without use of stream. Also, added some explanation.

Comment: plus 1 one then ;-)

Answer (score 0):

1) Split by space

2) Trim to remove extra spaces and replace everything strange with "" (remove)

3) Count words with more or equals to your minLength

### Example:

```
public class TesterClass
{
    public static void main (String args [])
    {
            String original = ",,, hello$hello asdasda ddd 33d   3333d        a";
            int minLength = 3;
            String[] words = original.split(" ");
            int count=0;

            for( String trimAndNoStrange : words)
            {
                String fixed = trimAndNoStrange.trim ( ).replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "").replaceAll("[0-9]", "");
                if(fixed.length ( ) >= minLength)
                {
                    count++;
                }
            }


            System.out.println("Number of words in sentence: " + count);

        }

}
```

### Example input/output:

> Input: ",,, hello$hello asdasda ddd 33d   3333d        a"
>
> Input: minLength = 3;
>
> Output: Number of words in sentence: 3

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the code to below

```
original = original.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z\\s]", "").replaceAll("[0-9]", "");
```

- replace as empty string instead of a space
- allow spaces exists (Add \s into the regex)

Comment: Tried this and it combines the entire sentence into one word. hello world becomes helloworld, so the output then becomes "Number of words in sentence: 1". Is there any way in which I can use split to break the words--because what seems to be happening is that a single word is passed into the array.

Comment: you can include the whitespace in your regex, For exmaple

Comment: "\\s" means white space, so you can use                                                    original = original.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z\\s]", "").replaceAll("[0-9]", "");

Answer (score 0):

You should focus on what you want to do instead of sneaking around your goal from opposite side. You want to *count words*, so just do that, instead of *replacing* or *splitting*.

One obstacle might be your special definition of “word”, but it’s worth spending some time thinking about the appropriate pattern, it will pay off more than spending time thinking about multiple replacement patterns plus a splitting pattern.

Ignoring the length constraint, a word is anything starting with a letter (digits and separators don’t count in your final task anyway), followed by an arbitrary number of non-space characters:

```
String s
    ="Spain is a beautiful country; the beache's are warm, sandy and spotlessly clean.";
int count=0;
for(Matcher m=Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z][^\\s]*").matcher(s); m.find();) {
    System.out.println(count+": "+m.group());
    count++;
}
System.out.println("total number of words: "+count);
```

will print:

```
0: Spain
1: is
2: a
3: beautiful
4: country;
5: the
6: beache's
7: are
8: warm,
9: sandy
10: and
11: spotlessly
12: clean.
total number of words: 13
```

Incorporating the minimum length, not counting non-letter characters, might be a bit tricky, but can be solved by considering that every letter might be followed by an arbitrary number of ignorable (i.e. non-letter non-space) characters and we just count the occurrences of that combination. So

```
String s
    ="Spain is a beautiful country; the beache's are warm, sandy and spotlessly clean.";
int count=0;
for(Matcher m=Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z][^A-Za-z\\s]*+){4,}").matcher(s); m.find();) {
    System.out.println(count+": "+m.group());
    count++;
}
System.out.println("total number of words >=4 letters: "+count);
```

prints

```
0: Spain
1: beautiful
2: country;
3: beache's
4: warm,
5: sandy
6: spotlessly
7: clean.
total number of words >=4 letters: 8
```

In case you’re wondering, the `*+` quantifier is like `*` but tells the regex engine not to do *backtracking* within that part of the match, which is an optimization in this context. Simply said, if the ignorable characters are not followed by a letter, there won’t be a letter within the ignorable characters either, so the engine should not spend time trying to find one there.

Bringing it into method form:

```
public static int countWords(String original, int minLength) {
    if(minLength<1) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    int count=0;
    for(Matcher m=Pattern.compile("([A-Za-z][^A-Za-z\\s]*+){"+minLength+",}")
                         .matcher(original); m.find();) {
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

and using it like

```
String s
    ="Spain is a beautiful country; the beache's are warm, sandy and spotlessly clean.";
for(int i=1; i<10; i++)
    System.out.println("with at least "+i+" letters: "+countWords(s, i));
```

yields

```
with at least 1 letters: 13
with at least 2 letters: 12
with at least 3 letters: 11
with at least 4 letters: 8
with at least 5 letters: 7
with at least 6 letters: 4
with at least 7 letters: 4
with at least 8 letters: 2
with at least 9 letters: 2
```